# Excel experiencing one-time delay during saving and quitting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, delay

On my work machine I have Excel 2003. The first time (per instance) I try to save a file or quit, there is a noticeable delay. For saving the delay is somewhere around 10-15 seconds and for quitting the delay is can be as long as 15-20 seconds, sometimes longer. However, this delay is one time per instance; i.e. if I load up Excel, save a document (experiencing a delay), the next time I try to save or quit, the operation completes instantly.

I've tried disabling add-ins, starting up in safe mode, and even unmapping all my mapped network drives. Nothing appears to work.

I've tried searching online but didn't find a response.

Any recommendations? My IT department isn't very helpful in these matters.

Comment: Are you saving to a newtork drive? A USB drive?

Comment: Seems the likely culprit would be what @DavidPostill has mentioned.

Comment: I meant **network** drive of course :/

Comment: No I'm not. The problem is the delay comes up before the Save dialog even opens. And what about quitting? Why would that cause a delay?